# How to stub javascript dependencies (jquery) in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine

I have some legacy code on my hands which was written with/relies upon the following stack:

- jquery 1.8.1
- jquery lazyload 1.8.0
- d3 v2

Before I change anything in the code, I figured I'd **write tests for it**, so I can make nothing brakes :).

- I chose the [jasmine test framework](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/) because I'm familiar with rspec

I'm running into some issues, because the **code I want to write tests for relies on jquery** to define some "constants" e.g:

```
var WIDTH = $(document).width();
```

I guess there is no way around stubbing.

1. Should I include jquery in jasmine and **try to spec the document?**
2. Or not include jquery in jasmine and **stub `$`**?

I fear I might be going down the wrong direction and would much appreciate some guidance (code snippets much appreciated). Thanks for helping a noob out!

Comment: Just curious: what kind of test cases you have? E.g. what are you trying to test?

Comment: No tests yet. I'm not very familiar with the code yet, it's about 2000 LOC, I'd be happy if I could create a test coverage where I'm confident that refactoring will not break behaviour. In the tests I'd probably be making assertions on dom element properties/attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would include jQuery and mock the functions that it calls.  In your example, I would do.

```
spyOn($.fn, 'width').andReturn(300); //Return a value that you expect to be used
```

Jasmine spies have a property `calls` that is an array of all the calls and one thing that I have done is examine the calls entries and you can check the calling object.  That being a jQuery object it has the property `selector` which you can expect to be equal to `document`

```
expect($.fn.width.calls[0].object.selector).toEqual(document);
```

Though remember you are trying to test the expected behavior of the code, not that each step of the code is completed as it is written.  Trying to test that certain lines exists will prevent you from easily refactoring.